# scrapy is slow (60 pages/min)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

my crawler seems to be working really slow, not sure why. ill try to explain how it works.

**keep in mind I use inline requests**

first i have 31 different starting URLs. each URL is a category in amazon.
settings:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201" 

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 2048

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2048
```

on each URL i do for on all the items in that page(16 items).

on each item i send a request to book scouter sell API and check the sell price.

after that i send  a request to book scouter buy API and check the buy price(its a different link, so 2 separate requests, one for buy one for sell).

after that i yield the ISBN, buy price and sell price.

now i check if the next page URL is string, if so crawl next page.

am i doing something wrong or that's the speed to be expected?

Comment: if you don't need,  don't use  download_delay

Comment: when i cancel the delay I'm getting 429, changed it to 0.5, I'm getting still some 429. is it because of the shitty API of book scouter?

Comment: Like the first comment you said you do not need download delay because you're not downloading anything your concurrence request is just way too high so you're throttling and of course you're going to get bumped out 403...  I would suggest to set your concur request her domain much lower lik 31 as well as enabling  Auto throttling

Comment: consider the possibility of breaking it down into two parts the extraction of the books from Amazon and then a complete other function to do just all the API calls... Threading in one go might not be your best option here particularly if you're dealing with api's that you might not be a paid service member of?? I assume