# scrapy how to make custom delay

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

i want to make a custom delay because global delay is inefficient in my code.

since i didn't know what i was looking for in this thread: [scrapy is slow (60 pages/min)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568502/scrapy-is-slow-60-pages-min)
i decided its better to ask it as a new question.

basically i have:

```
amazon request
API request
API request
```

if i use DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
its like having:

```
amazon request
delay(1)
API request
delay(1)
API request
delay(1)
```

when i actually only need:

```
amazon request
API request
delay(1)
API request
delay(1)
```

how can i implement the delay? i dont think scrapy have this function.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2897) out, it might give support in future.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the sleep function from the time module in python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html.

Its parameter is in seconds so the code would go:

```
from time import sleep
amazon request
API request
sleep(1)
API request
sleep(1)
```

Comment: people say you should not use sleep in scrapy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171239/scrapy-is-it-possible-to-pause-scrapy-and-resume-after-x-minutes "Scrapy is a Twisted-based Python framework. So, never use time.sleep or pause.until inside it! Instead, try using Deferred() from Twisted."